# R shiny: How to connect with fifleinput and ggplot without any selectioninput?

Tags: r, ggplot2, file-io, shiny, shinydashboard

I am doing my first shiny app by using shiny dashboard. I get stuck in how to let users to upload in shiny app and show a bar chart(ggplot) in the Shiny App.

I already complete the data upload process(fileinput with any txt/CVS files and show the outline in the Shiny App website).  But I don't know how to show the plot in Shiny app website under different tabname by using the data user uploaded in the shiny dashboard.

Please help me, thank you so much!

Ui ：

```
    # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "databrowse",
            fileInput('infile', 'Choose text/csv file to upload',
                      accept = c(
                          'text/csv',
                          'text/comma-separated-values',
                          '.csv'
                      )),
            radioButtons("separator","Separator: ",choices = c(";",",",":"), selected=",",inline=TRUE),
            DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table")
    ),

    # Third tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "Usage",
            plotlyOutput('MyPlot')
            )
    )
```

Server:

```
df_products_upload <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$infile
    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE,sep = input$separator)
    return(df)
})

output$sample_table<- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- df_products_upload()
    DT::datatable(df)
})
```

# Variables: Date, Time, Usage

```
#####################################

output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(df())
    })
 ??????????????????# cannot figure out , how to output this plot   
###########################################
```

Comment: Perhaps your question should be how to generate a plotly histogram *outside of `shiny`*. If your `df_products_upload` data is non-empty, then I think you can remove all of the shiny stuff and just focus on the smaller-picture for now.

Comment: But shouldn't you be using `plotly::renderPlotly` instead of `shiny::renderPlot`?

Comment: What the difference between plotly::renderPlotly and shiny::renderPlot?

Comment: df_products_upload is empty, I separately made a ggplot with my data, it works. I really do not know how to combine the empty data and the ggplot. I google, google and google, still didn't find a simple example. I find so many complex examples with many selectinput. And I cannot understand.......

Comment: I don't understand how you intend to plot empty data. I think there is a lot of confusion here: you show `hist()` (base graphics) in a `renderPlot` (again, base) but defined within `plotlyOutput` (not base), and then you mention `ggplot`, which is neither base nor (generally) plotly. What graphing engine are you trying to use: base, ggplot, or plotly? They are not compatible. If you don't know, then perhaps you're reaching a little too far ahead in creating an app (not meant as discouragement, more so to help you take small steps forward, not leaps and bounds).

Comment: Thank you so much！ My idea is that to create a website, and in this website, I can upload my data, and it can directly show in different plots in  different sheets. I want it can be similar to be a simple data visualization tool. But after start to do it, I become confused.

Comment: I understand. In general, `shiny::renderPlot` will work with base or `ggplot2`, but not `plotly`. I suggest you start by using `plotOutput` (from `shiny`) and not plotly. Again, for now. Then, realize that in your use, `df()` is a full `data.frame` potentially with many columns; if you intend a faceted plot (such as `hist(mtcars)` gives you), then you're fine, otherwise you might need to include column-selectors (`selectInput`, reactive to `df_products_upload()`'s column names.